# conda create --name doc-env python==3.7 pero la version dado con -V esta 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

Intento instalar python 3.7 con conda pero cada vez parece que me pone python 3.11. Entonces intenté especificar explícitamente el canal con `conda create --name doc-env python=3.7 -c conda-forge` Me he dado cuenta de que no se ve el entorno entre paréntesis a la izquierda. Cómo puedo instalar mi versión de python en mi entorno? Aparte de Anaconda, no tengo Python en mi máquina. Parece que es a causa de `which python` que no apunta en la dirrecion correcta. En efecto da:

```
/c/Users/antoi/anaconda3/python
```

Mientras que debria devolver:

```
/c/Usuarios/antoi/anaconda3/envs/doc-env/bin/python
```

Sospecho que mi terminal no puede cargar el entorno. No sé lo suficiente acerca de los terminales de Windows para aconsejar una solución por desgracia

He aquí cómo se creó el entorno y el error. Si quieres replicarlo. O ver lo que llevó al error:

```
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> conda create --name doc-env python==3.7        
WARNING: A conda environment already exists at 'C:\Users\antoi\anaconda3\envs\doc-env'
Remove existing environment (y/[n])? Y

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.7.4
  latest version: 23.9.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=23.9.0



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\antoi\anaconda3\envs\doc-env

  added / updated specs:
    - python==3.7


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-3.7.0               |       hea74fb7_0        16.6 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        16.6 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  certifi            pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2022.12.7-py37haa95532_0
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-22.3.1-py37haa95532_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-65.6.3-py37haa95532_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.2-h21ff451_1
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016-h5e58377_2
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.38.4-py37haa95532_0
  wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py37haa95532_2


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate doc-env
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> conda activate doc-env
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> python -V
Python 3.11.5
```

Comment: Hola, me parece que a veces powershell no tiene permisos para ejecutar scripts de powershell, usando la consola de powershell como admin ingresa este comando ```set-executionpolicy unrestricted``` para habilitar la ejecución de scripts de powershell y luego esto ```conda init powershell``` para inicializar conda